# How do I get the domain of the request origin from my SvelteKit API

Tags: sveltekit, caddy

I'm currently testing locally. I'm making requests from localhost:5001 to localhost:5002, where my SvelteKit API lives. When I log the headers, I see localhost:5001 only in the referer header, which I understand can be easily modified by the sender:

```js
export async function GET({ request, params, fetch }) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url)
  const headers = request.headers
  const origin = headers.get('referer')
  console.log(origin)

  ...
}
```

This API will eventually live behind a Caddy server as a reverse proxy.